# spirit: uint parser: parse a number between 1..31

Tags: integer, boost-spirit-qi

I use uint_parser to parse at most 2 consecutive digits.
However I would like parsing to fail if the parsed integer is outside of the range [1,31]?
For now, I take care of that in the semantic action.

Are there recommendations re detecting errors at parsing level vs at semantic action user code level?

Comment: Btw, I will try to use   _pass = false   inside the semantic action to indicate parse failure when the number parsed is outside the desired range

Comment: Another alternative is to explicitly parse with char_. Ie, char_(0) followed by char_('1','9') or char_('1','2') followed by char_('0','9') or char_('3') followed by char_('0','1') or char_('1','9')